# Why are HTML attributes missing in a Bootstrap 4 popover?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("[data-toggle=popover]").popover({
            html: true,
            content: function () {
                return "<div style='color:red;'>test</div>";
            }
        });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<a class="btn btn-primary" data-html="true" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom">Click Me</a>
```

When I use HTML content in a Bootstrap 4 popover, the HTML attributes are missing. I expect to see red text, but it outputs the div tag without the red style.

```
    $("[data-toggle=popover]").popover({
        html: true,
        content: function () {
            return "<div style='color: red;'>Test</div>";
        }
    });
```

Comment: Well did you check your dev tools? Maybe something is overwriting the rule. try adding important. Its hard someone will be able to help without a way to reproduce a problem. You should make a example.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can add a class and set css to that:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
    html: true,
    content: function() {
      return "<div class='color-red'>Test</div>";
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.color-red{ color: red; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<a href="#" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover">Test</a>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks. It turned out it was my version of bootstrap. Whatever version I was using was stripping out all the attributes of html elements.

Comment: I experienced the same. It turned out that it's working in Bootstrap 4.0.0 & 4.3.0, but since 4.4.0 the popover seems to filter most html attributes  ("id", "class", will show up, most others e.g. "data" will not). Seems like some undocumented feature (bug?) in Bootstrap.

Answer (score 16):

Bootstrap popovers perform some sanitizing to strip "unsafe" attributes - and it's turned on by default.

Contradicting my previous comment and my tests, it has been default even in older versions. It's always good to know the manual :-)

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/popovers/#options

Allowed attributes are defined tagwise:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/#js-sanitizer

It can be switched off setting the `sanitize` option to false.

```
$("[data-toggle=popover]").popover({
  html: true,
  sanitize: false,
  content: function () {
    return "<div style='color: red;'>Test</div>";
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you!!   You saved me a lot of headaches.